# html to pdf convert, cyrillic characters not displayed properly

Tags: pdf, encoding, fonts, itext

I have a problem with pdf fonts. I have used a method for generating pdf from html which worked fine on my local machine which is windows OS, but now on linux Cyrillic text is displayed with question marks. I checked for fonts there but it turned out that there were required fonts. Now I switched to another method which is shown below.

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    String myFontsDir = "C:\\";
    String filePath = AppProperties.downloadLocation + "Order_" + orderID + ".pdf";
    try {
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        int iResult = FontFactory.registerDirectory(myFontsDir);
        if (iResult == 0) {
            System.out.println("TestPDF(): Could not register font directory " + myFontsDir);
        } else {
            System.out.println("TestPDF(): Registered font directory " + myFontsDir);
        }

        document.open();
        String htmlContent = "<html><head>"
                + "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8\"/>"
                + "</head>"
                + "<body>"
                + "<h4 style=\"font-family: arialuni, arial; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal; \" >"
                + "Здраво Kristijan!"
                + "</h4></body></html>";
        InputStream inf = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(myFontsDir);
        FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, inf, null, null, fontImp);

        document.close();
        System.out.println("Done.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

with this peace of code I am able to generate proper pdf from latin text, but cyrillic is displayed with weird characters. This happens on Windows, I haven't yet test it on Linux. Any advice for encoding or font?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First this: it is very hard to believe that your font directory is `C:\\`. You are assuming that you have a file with path `C:\\arialuni.ttf` whereas I assume that the path to MS Arial Unicode is `C:\\windows\fonts\arialuni.ttf`.

Secondly: I don't think `arialuni` is the correct name. I'm pretty sure it's `arial unicode ms`. You can check this by running this code:

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
fontProvider.register("c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf");
for (String s : fontProvider.getRegisteredFamilies()) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The output should be:

```
courier
arial unicode ms
zapfdingbats
symbol
helvetica
times
times-roman
```

These are the values you can use; `arialuni` isn't one of them.

Also: aren't you defining the character set in the wrong place?

I have slightly adapted your source code in the sense that I stored the HTML in an HTML file [cyrillic.html](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/cyrillic.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h4 style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS, FreeSans; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal; " >Здраво Kristijan!</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I replaced `arialuni` with `Arial Unicode MS` and that I used `FreeSans` as an alternative font. In my code, I used `FreeSans.ttf` instead of `arialttf`.

See [ParseHtml11](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtml11):

```
public static final String DEST = "results/xmlworker/cyrillic.pdf";
public static final String HTML = "resources/xml/cyrillic.html";
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";

public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
    fontImp.register(FONT);
    FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
            new FileInputStream(HTML), null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, I use the `Charset` when parsing the HTML. The result looks like this:

[image]

If you insist on using Arial Unicode, just replace this line:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
```

With this one:

```
public static final String FONT = "c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf";
```

I have tested this on a Windows machine and it works too:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's true what you wrote, I intentionally left that path and my font is indeed arialuini.ttf. Anyway, I solve the problem, which it turned out to be that my Linux machine didn't properly installed my fonts. Thank you man, you helped me earlier with this problem!

Comment: Hi @Chris, I see from your reputation that you are an experienced user, why wouldn't you accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I must have  forgotten at the time. Thanks for the remainder

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, What if we dont have file ? just a plain text? not file