# Cyrillic letters showing while PDF creation via iText

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I have HTML page with Cyrillic letters and I use [iText](http://itextpdf.com) library for conversion from HTML to PDF. I don't use iText directly and use `XMLWorkerHelper` for doing conversion:

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContentString.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
document.close();
writer.close();
file.close();
```

Unfortunately, I can't see Cyrillic letters in output PDF file at all.

How can I prepare source HTML file (some font tags, CSS attributes etc.) for getting PDF output properly?

Comment: @AndyTurner Here and how I should specify it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html to pdf convert, cyrillic characters not displayed properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889217/html-to-pdf-convert-cyrillic-characters-not-displayed-properly)

Comment: You should specify an `XMLWorkerFontProvider` instance

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the problem is **iText** internally uses a font without Cyrillic letters for PDF rendering.

So the solution is defining a font **with** Cyrillic letters for any PDF elements (e.g. default Windows *Arial* font). It's possible to do via specifying CSS file in `parseXHtml` call as a parameter:

```
...
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is, getStylesStream());
...
private InputStream getStylesStream() {
    return PdfReport.class.getResourceAsStream("/reports/styles.css");
}
```

and in `styles.css` should be

```
* {
    /* Enforces to use font with Cyrillic letters */
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

However, this approach looses any default iText styling. So I copied in my styles.css all content of *default.css* file from *xmlworker.jar*.

Unfortunately, ability to change content of default.css after its loading in memory (via XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCSS()) is prohibited.